# ExpressJS, how to route to my function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to expressJS, nodeJS and hope some kind souls would enlighten me on routing.

I have this line in app.js

```
var core = require('./routes/core/'),
app.get ('/core/:base/:methodfunc', core);
```

The end result I would like to achieve is when i pass in /core/testmethod/test from the URL, I am able to access test function in testmethod file

The routing :base param is to route to testmethod.js and :methodfunc method is the exported function in testmethod

This is my main code in /core
**index.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {
    var base = req.params.base;
    var methodfunc = req.params.methodfunc;
    var basePage = require('./' + base);

    if (basePage) {
        if (methodfunc) {
            basePage.methodfunc(req, res); //there is something very wrong here
        } else {
            fail();
        }
    } else {
        fail();
    }

    function fail() {
        res.send(404);
    }
}
```

**testmethod.js function**

```
exports.test = function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        name: 'hello there'
    });
};
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to call the function by name so it would be:

```
basePage[methodfunc](req, res);
```